# How to modify the twisted log format？

Tags: logging, twistd

I use the twisted's `DailyLogFile`,and run like this:

```
twistd --logfile=test.log myserver_tapname
```

The log file like this:

```
test.log.2014_3_9
```

But i hope the log like this:

```
test.log.2014_03_09
```

How can I format that output filename?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Given a file named my.py with the code:

```
from twisted.python.log import FileLogObserver
import time
extension = time.strftime("%Y_%m_%d")
def logger():
    return FileLogObserver(open("/tmp/test.log."+extension, "w")).emit
```

invoking

```
 twistd --logger my.logger ...
```

will log to a file named `/tmp/test.log.2014_03_28.log`

Comment: I overload the logfile.DailyLogFile's suffix method. Thank you all the same.